# Why browsers does not render trailing <br> in <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a div with dynamic content where lines are delimited by `<br>` element. The problem is that all major browser ignores the last `<br>` element.

```
<div>
    long content ...
</div>
<div>
    long content ...
    <br>
</div>
<div>
    long content ...
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/4ppqb1ug/. Example have 3 divs.

- First have no `<br>` at end.
- Second have 1 `<br>` at end but if you scroll the div at bottom no blank line is at end.
- The third one have 2 `<br>` at end, but only one is rendered.
- the fourth not present in demo have 3 `<br>`, only 2 are rendered.
- the fifth not present in demo have 4 `<br>`, only 3 are rendered.

[image: Missing trailing br]

Why are browser ignoring the last one? Could I prevent this? Is there better solution than duplicationg the last `<br>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there better solution than duplicationg the last `<br>`?

Yes, there is:

```css
.container:after {
  content: '\2060'
}
```

We're choosing to append a pseudo-element containing a [word joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner) character. It's effectively the same as just adding another `<br>`, but it's a pure CSS solution that is invisible to the user. This character could be anything that is zero width as long as it makes the browser honour the last `<br>` in our content.

Answer (score 2):

The browsers are behaving correctly; you are just incorrectly thinking of `br` elements as spacers.

As stated in [the HTML 5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element), they are line breaks. Each one of those elements will return the carriage to the next line, but will not print anything on that line. It's only until you add a second one that the space of the first line is represented.

The answer to your second question is, yes, there is a better solution to this problem: use CSS to set the `margin` or `padding` of those `div` elements. This keeps the structure (HTML) separated from the presentation (CSS).

Answer (score 1):

I never have used `<br>` for this. You can easily manage this by using p tag. There are also text formatting css rules like `line-height`, `font-size`, ... . You can easily use these and create good looking text. And whenever you need to break line for a new paragraph, the standard way is to use another p tag, not `<br>`.

Comment: This is best practice not a answer. Manually setting this properties is complicated for me. Example is very simplified.

Comment: Well anyway just wanted to share idea.

Comment: By the way, everything is hard for anyone the first time. Never get tired.

Comment: I have many project completed as you descriped but this is different. Div don't contains paragraphs but something totally different. Rewrite to using paragraphs is very complicated not only at frontend but the main problem is on backend. So I am looking if there are any easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

`br` tag  only use line break,  not possible prevent, it solutin you can using `padding and margin` last  div  span  and other

Answer (score 1):

It is because `<br>` doesn't render any blank space. If you want to have a blank line you need to have two `<br>` tags